# How to make 'checked' checkboxes, impossible to uncheck

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Basically, I create a checkbox range with pure JS. What I can't figure out, how to make checked range impossible to uncheck. For example you check **2** and **5**. So number **3** and **4** should be impossible to uncheck, but **2** and **5** is possible to uncheck.

```
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="1">One</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="2">Two</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="3">Three</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="4">Four</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="5">Five</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="6">Six</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="7">Seven</input></li>
</ul>


// JavaScript
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
var lastChecked = null;

// Iterate through every 'input' element and add an event listener = click
for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
  el[i].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {
  // In this statement we check, which input is checked..✓
  if (!lastChecked) {
      lastChecked = this;
    return;
  }

// Declaring 'from' and 'to' and getting index number of an array-like inputs
var from = [].indexOf.call(el, this);
var to = [].indexOf.call(el, lastChecked);

 /* Here we will know which 'check' will be the min and which will be the max with the 
 help of Math metods */
var start = Math.min(from, to);
var end = Math.max(from, to) + 1;

// Here we create an array from NodeList
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(el);

// Here we get a new array, where we declare the start and the end
// Start is the min, end is the max
var slicedArr = arr.slice(start, end);

// Now we iterate through every sliced input, and set its attribute to checked
for(var j = 0; j < slicedArr.length; j++){
    slicedArr[j].checked = lastChecked.checked;
}

lastChecked = this;

}
```

Thank you for any help guys. It is my first post on stackoverflow by the way, so I'm verry sorry if I didn't post it correctly. Thank you.

Comment: you need a max of two checkboxes to be checked? If so, (supposing max is 2) then we go through the loop of input items that are not checked and disable them

Comment: some kind of two-way binding library (i.e. Vue) would make this trivial. Are you restricted to pure JS ?

Comment: @Jayanth it can be a bigger range. For example from 1 to 7. But the point is to make the range 'uncheckable'. So in this case it would be numbers 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: @ Alex Yes, I am limited just to pure JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the element via attribute selector

```
for (let i=start; i<=end; i++){
    document.querySelector(`[value="${i}"]`).disabled = true;
}
```

Here it is building the string in the selector with template literals 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

And just setting the disabled attribute in the checkboxes via Javascript

```
document.querySelector('[value="7"]').disabled = true;
```

it will get an HTML like

```
<input type="checkbox" value="7" disabled>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_disabled.asp

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to make checkboxes uncheckable.

Sure, you can use

`document.getElementById("elemnt-id").disabled = true;`

or via

`disabled` attribute in `html`,

but there's always a way to uncheck them manually via `Developer tools`. So you should have some validation on server too.

Comment: Thank you very much @htshame

Comment: @JustMartin you should accept the most helpful answer